# Org-mode Babels :file with link abbreviations

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I have some link-abbreviations in org-mode like this:

```
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist
  '(("dropboxpath" . "~/Dropbox")
    ("cloudpath" . "~/")
    ("imgpath" . "~/images")
    ("gitpath" . "~/git")
    ))
```

It works fine and as i am working on different systems and syncing my org-files the paths are different on every system. My problem is the following:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file gitpath:/test.png
<some plantumlstuff here>
#+END_SRC
```

This is not working, org-babel does not recognize the link abbreviation.
I also tried the following (where temp is a variable containing the path to the git-directory):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file (concat temp "/test.png")
```

This works in principle but gives me the following result:

```
#+RESULTS:
[[file:~/git/test.png]]
```

This does not meet my requirements though because i need gitpath in order to make it work over all my machines...

```
#+RESULTS:
[[gitpath:/test.png]]
```

Does anybody have a suitable solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply refer to `org-link-abbrev-alist`.  Since that variable is structured as an [alist](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AssociationList), you can use `assoc`.  It returns the first element of the alist that matches the supplied key.

```
(concat
  (car (assoc "gitpath" org-link-abbrev-alist))
  "/test.png")
```

Comment: That does not create the desired effect. As i described this would give me something like this:
#+RESULTS:
[[file:~/git/test.png]]
but i want something like this
#+RESULTS:
[[gitpath:/test.png]]

Comment: The output reflects the actual accurate path on your local system.  Are you syncing or versioning the output files?  If so: Why?

Comment: I am aware of this behavior. I am syncing the output but the paths can change anyways, that’s what I am using the abbreviations for. They are different on the different setups (like on my laptop gitpath = ~/git and on my pc it is gitpath = c:/users/.../git). I either need babel to recognize the abbreviation or to replace the path with it after the link has been inserted. (Why am I synching? E.g. because not all systems have java installed [needed for plantuml], other reasons available, too ;)

Comment: (other reasons could be: I had to regenerate all the output when i visit a file on another system [and the new path gets synced and i have to regenerate on the old system], I will be using a server-solution to display my org-files on my webpage and it a requirement for me that it does not have to regenerate, etc.)